# Keepin the x and y scale to max values with defined intervals in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data frame values and have plotted it with the help of ggplot the code I have is as follows:

```
ggplot(lung_dfdsa, aes(x=z_lung_con, y=lung_dsa)) + geom_point(shape=21, colour = "blue")+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20,2)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20,by= 2)) +geom_smooth(method=lm)+ labs(x = "Measured lung expression values", y = "Estimated lung expression values") + theme_bw() + theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

This code creates a graph with the axis limits upto 14 because there is data only upto that, but what I would want is to have the max limit upto 20 with the intervals I have defined even if there aren't any values in the dataset upto that range. Is that possible?

Comment: post your data please

Comment: The data is huge and I cannot post it. But, for the question I have asked I don't think data is needed just would want to know how to fix the end values with defined intervals even if the data points are not there for those end values.Thanks

Comment: @Venkat you can use `expand_limits`.  See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/expand_limits.html

Comment: that did the trick Thank you @steveb. could you post this as the answer so I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expand_limits`. See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/expand_limits.html